# How can I set default image in property if image is not available for a product in media file(django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am learning django from youtube channel(Dennis Ivy).I want to set default image in property if image is not found for a product.Please help me.
[image: Models.py]
[image: Homepage.html]
[image: views.py]

[image: This is my homepage,where you can see image for headphone is not available,I want to fill this type of blank with default image]

Comment: Why can't you just have a default image in your project folder and provide the url where you have the question mark in the first image?

Comment: Yes I have default image in 'static/images/default.jpg' ,but don't know how to code.I had used url='/static/images/default.jpg' in property but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to define the default image in your model fields, rather than building a function for that. And you need to define where you want to upload the image:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True, default="path to default image")
```

You would use it on the template like:

```
{{ product.image }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use builtin **[`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#default)** filter as follows:

**`{{ product.imageURL|default:'/images/product-img-default.png' }}`**

replace `/images/product-img-default.png` with your default image path